# mac fails to reconnect to SMB share after coming back from suspend

Tags: file-sharing, smb

I've got a mac (OS X 10.8.2) that's accessing files on an Win7 SMB share. About half the time the Mac comes back from suspend it can't connect to the SMB share. The Win7 machine is on and the password hasn't changed. But when I try to connect to the SMB server it asks for the username/password. When I type it in, I get told it's wrong. Then I restart the machine (Mac) and it can connect to the SMB server fine.

It's an annoyance really, especially when I've got 8 different terminal windows open and they're all named the way I like etc.

Anyone got a suggestion/tips for re-connecting to an SMB drive after suspend?

Comment: why are you running 10.8.2 and not 10.8.5?

Comment: Because this question is a year old.

Comment: see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153754/smb-auto-unmount-then-unable-to-re-mount-without-restart/190740#190740

Answer (score 0):

Mounting an SMB share as a local folder seems more reliable than using the Finder sidebar or even COMM-K to connect. It shouldn't be, right, but it is for me. Half the time, the Finder sidebar option won't connect even though I can still access the networked folder. Here's an example of using mount_smbfs:

`mount_smbfs //Guest@10.0.1.1/myshare /Users/user/Downloads/networkfolder`

Also, I had to disable sleep completely because the video crashes reliably on wake. 2018 mini with BigSûr. It fixed the problem.

Comment: If sleep is disabled, does your Mac ever need to reconnect to a SMB share?

Comment: FYI - the man page says `Note: You should always use the system mount command and never call mount_smbfs directly`