# How to debug Mac servers (with file sharing) when the SMB shares disconnect on the client side?

Tags: macos, mac, network, smb

We have multiple Mac OS/OSX servers (A mix of El Cap and High Sierra) that have SMB shares mounted for backing /archiving jobs (chronosync and P5)

The SMB shares are connected via "connect to server" and generally remain stable, but become unmounted randomly at least once every 1-2 days.

The goal here is to keep the SMB shares mounted at all cost.

I've read around on StackExchange and tried analysing the network connections using the command from this post:

[SMB: auto-unmount then unable to re-mount without restart](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153754/smb-auto-unmount-then-unable-to-re-mount-without-restart#new-answer?newreg=7b077a02b1474ea1b1fa66cd9e30236b)

```
netstat -I
ping -c 90 -i 10 your_SMB_server
tail -f /var/log/system.log
```

No errors or issues with the packets found.

I'm sure there's a sys admin expert out that must have solved this already ;)

Appreciate any suggestions or ideas, however rudimentary

Is there any way analyze the logs (We've looked in system.log) and find the reason for the unmount?

Comment: What's the server? Are you sure the server isn't kicking them off, perhaps if inactive?

Comment: +1 for more info in the sever. For instance, there is a config option in Samba which disconnects inactive connections after a certain period of time. Also, it would probably make more sense to look at the sever logs.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys, super helpful. Seems logical to reason that the disconnects would be logged with the server rather than the client. These are ReadyNAS, Synology and TigerBox storage, all using SMB shares.

I'll look into the SMB settings and logs of the servers and report back here

Comment: Are you looking for a tool like these to make sure the clients reconnect no matter why the share isn't mounted? https://www.apple.com/business/docs/site/Kerberos_Single_Sign_on_Extension_User_Guide.pdf and https://www.jamf.com/blog/migrating-from-nomad-to-jamf-connect/

Answer (score 3):

Not certain I understand the context of your question, so let's try this first:

This has worked for me:

1. Mount the SMB/CIFS share using Finder's `Go, Connect to Server...`.
2. If prompted for credentials, and given the option, store those credentials in the `Keychain`
3. Open `System Preferences, Users and Groups`; select the `Login Items` tab near the top
4. Click the `+` button at the bottom of the list of login items to "add" an item.
5. This will produce a new `Finder` window that allows you to select an item. Simply navigate to the mounted SMB/CIFS share from the `Sidebar`, select/highlight the SMB/CIFS share of interest, then click the `Add` button in the bottom right of the Finder window.

This should dismiss the `Finder` window, and now the share should be mounted at each login. Let us know if this doesn't work/isn't what you needed.

#### EDIT/UPDATE (May 28,2023):

Apple's `autofs` may be a good candidate for keeping network shares mounted - regardless of what causes the loss of connectivity. Briefly, `autofs` has been around for a while, and works on most versions of macOS - even on those ***before and after*** the introduction of the ***read-only filesystem*** which was introduced in macOS Catalina. FWIW, I currently use `autofs` on my new macOS M2 running Ventura.

Some minor adjustments to the `/etc/auto_master` file are required to accommodate the read-only file system; these changes are covered in an [answer to a similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/457190/149366).

Here are some other potentially useful references from my GitHub site:

1. [AutoFS Example](https://github.com/seamusdemora/seamusdemora.github.io/blob/master/AutoFS-AnExamplePeristentMountForSynologyNAS.md)
2. [AutoFS Technical White Paper by Apple; dtd Jun 2009](https://github.com/seamusdemora/seamusdemora.github.io/blob/master/AutoFS.md)

Answer (score 1):

There is an OpenSource app doing just that, take a look at  https://gitlab.rrze.fau.de/faumac/networkShareMounter
It is meant for MDM administrators but can be used without configuration profiles at home or in a non-enterprise or non-university environment.