# Can I use Applescript to have Safari save a specific page’s contents as source?

Tags: macos, applescript, safari, automator

I need to have Safari visit a specific URL, and "Save As... page source" to a specified location in my `Home` folder. I don't want to actually see Safari while this is going on - unless that's unavoidable.  I understand this is *do-able* using AppleScript, but I have zero experience with that. I tried using the `Automator` app to generate something, but I’m stuck at the first step.

Can someone show me how this is done?

Comment: How do you get the 'specific url'?

Comment: @Mockman: For the purposes of this Q, it can be **any** URL. You can use [this one](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/text-mode-web-browsers) if you like.

Comment: If you plan on using this regularly, how will you feed that url to the script/app/service? Will it be on the clipboard? Will it be selected text in a file? I'll assume that it's on the clipboard.

Comment: @Mockman It will **always** be the same URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an automator document. While testing, make it a workflow. Once you've got it working the way you like, you can make an application or whatever is most useful.

Add two actions, both from the Internet category:

1. **Get specified URLs**
2. **Download URLs**

With the first action, click the expand triangle and if there is a default URL in there, select it and click `Remove` and then `Add` your specific URL.

With the second action, click the Where dropdown and choose a destination. Click 'other' to choose an arbitrary location. It might be worthwhile to have an exclusive folder specified as then you could easily run other actions on the 'contents' of the folder (see below).

Then click 'Run' to test the workflow. It should download the html for the page (but not all of the ancillary files) and save it in the specified location. If it already exists, it will save an additional copy.

This is probably the easiest method to download a web page and doesn't require that Safari actually open the page. You could also use applescript or you could use a command-line tool like *wget* or *curl* and run it from the terminal.

**Update:**

To make this into an app rather than a workflow, it's probably easiest to simply create a new app and then add the actions the same way that the workflow was created. Unfortunately, the `file > convert to…` menu command doesn't seem very effective.

As to renaming the resulting file, unfortunately the `download urls` action doesn't seem to work as it might as it does not provide a result (ie a reference to the saved html).

You can add a workaround though. Here is one that uses the saved file (so you have to download the file so you can then 'choose' it) and then renames that — note that you can then remove/trash that initial file as you only need it long enough to add the entry to the action. I use the 'add date or time' option in the 'rename finder items' action because it doesn't require user interaction but you can go through the various options and choose the best for your need.

3. **Get specified finder items**
   This uses `add` to specify the file so you must have a file in the download location with the correct name and then choose it (eg 'text-mode-web-browsers.html'). This is the name that the two-step download would generate based on your supplied url. Run it again with the actual url to get the correct file name for that url. Note, you don't need the actual file, just the actual file name, so you could also just stick a random text file there and give it the same name and then trash it.
4. **Rename finder items: add date or time**
   You can choose your renaming options for this action but
   the date/time one is easy to work with. Note that some rename options seem to function only in a workflow.

Comment: Haha... I know all about wget & curl... believe me, if I could use them - I would. They are both blocked by this website.

Comment: Hey - very good - it works! Can you embellish it a little bit to save it as a different filename... by that I mean I'd like to set the filename to save as. And I don't want an additional copy created, but overwriting is OK.

Comment: *"Once you've got it working the way you like, you can make an application or whatever is most useful."*  I'm going to run it autonomously via `cron` or as a "UserAgent" under LaunchControl, so maybe I should make it an app??  How do I do that?

Comment: The easiest way would be to just start with a new application. Add the two actions. You will find that the app defaults to `application receives files and folders as input`, which you don't want. Right-click on the first action and select `ignore input`. You will probably have to run the app at least once to let the OS know that it's legitimate. There may be some other security measures depending upon your OS version.

Answer (score 1):

This post is to **augment** the [accepted answer fm @Mockman](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/469541/149366):

1. Following the accepted answer's advice using `Automator` led to the successful creation of a `workflow` file. In my case, I saved this as `getwebpage.workflow` (catchy name, eh?).
2. I could run my `getwebpage.workflow` from `Automator`, but that was **not** what I expected for **Automation**... what do I **do** with a `workflow` file? ... how do I run it as a "stand-alone" ... is this even possible?

   Stumbling blindly through the wasteland known as **Apple's Documentation** led nowhere (as usual), but I did find something in a search that proved to be **The Answer**:

   As it turns out, there is a command line app also named `automator`!!  And it has a `man page` (wonders never cease):

   ```
   NAME  
     automator – Runs Automator workflow   

   SYNOPSIS  
     automator [-v] [-i input] [-D name=value ...] workflow  

   DESCRIPTION  
     automator runs the specified workflow.  To create or edit a workflow, use the Automator application.

     The following options are available:

     -D name=value
              Set variable name to value for this run of workflow.

     -i input
              Set input as the input to workflow.  If input is - then the contents of standard input is used.  Each newline (\n)-terminated line is treated as one
              text input item.

     -v       Run in verbose mode.

   Mac OS X                                                                    April 1, 2007                                                                    Mac OS X
   ```

Armed with this information, I was able to create a small `bash` script around `automator`, and create a "Global Daemon" in [`LaunchControl`](https://soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) to run it on a schedule.

#### Afterword:

My **incredulity and sarcasm here mask my appreciation** at finding a solution; this solution filled a real need for me. But I cannot help but wonder: ***Why*** does Apple develop a solution like Automator, let it languish for 17 years, but leave it in the distribution with only the scantest of documentation? The same question could be asked re [Apple's `AutoFS`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/457190/149366).
<sub>Yes, these are  rhetorical questions.</sub>

##### P.S.

As it turns out, there ***is*** some [documentation on the Automator](https://support.apple.com/guide/automator/intro-to-automator-aut6e8156d85/2.10/mac/14.0).
<sub>It goes well with this tasty crow.</sub>