# Stop server(?) from asking for re-authentication when re-mounting an SMB?

Tags: network, mount, smb

I am working within a medium sized organisation, mix of Macs/Windows machines etc, with a variety of shared drives with access control via a central active directory/LDAP login (I don't know all the specifics).

I mount a shared drive (which I have permission to access) via <kbd>⌘/cmd</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> then:

> smb://server_name/orgdata/biostats

It prompts for my password (or used to before I saved it in the keychain) then mounts. It works great.

**PROBLEM:** I take my MacBook Pro home, change location from work to roaming, then come back to work the next day, change my location from roaming back to work. Then try to mount the SMB again and I get.

[image]

Unfortunately it will just reject my user name/password over and over.

I have to reboot before I can remount the drive.

I can also see that my list of 'volumes' occasionally gets out of wack.

[image]

**QUESTION:** Is there a way around this? A better way to mount the SMB? A server setting I should ask IT to change so I don't get this odd authentication clash (if that's what it is).

Dupe? Likely related to this issue [mac fails to reconnect to SMB share after coming back from suspend](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73724/mac-fails-to-reconnect-to-smb-share-after-coming-back-from-suspend) but that is unanswered.

Comment: Already tried to destroy your Kerberos ticket(s) before mounting the shares after returning to work? `klist` to list them. Either`kdestroy -p Principal` (with Principal probably something like username@LKDC:SHA1......) to destroy one or `kdestroy -a` to destroy all.

Comment: Thanks @klanomathbut didn't work. Ejecting the Shared drive before disconnecting seems to work (but who has the time! - kidding), but that isn't always fool proof.