# How can I keep a connection to a file server active?

Tags: finder, network, wifi, sleep-wake, smb

I have an M1 mac mini connected to my television. I use it to watch content including a library of movies stored on a Windows file server. I access these files using the "connect to server..." feature in Finder, which works great.

If I pause a movie and go away for a day, the mac mini goes to sleep, which is a good thing. But when I wake it up and resume playing a movie, I find the server connection is lost, and I have to re-do the "connect to server" process in Finder again.

On my Windows computers, this all works normally. It is just the mac that seems to disconnect and stay disconnected when it goes to sleep, even when applications are using the connection...

How do I make a persistent connection to a file server that stays active and automatically reconnects when the mac wakes from sleep?

Thanks!

Comment: Existing Q/A: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/73724/119271